# Sequences with Tetrahedral Stacks of Oranges

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

A grocer stacks oranges into a tetrahedral pyramid (i.e, a pyramid with a triangular base and
3 triangular sides). Let Cn be the total number of oranges where n is the height (number of levels)
in the pyramid. (C1 = 1, C2 = 4, C3 = 10, etc.). Give a closed-form formula for Cn and report the
value for C100.

This is what I have tried so far but I am unsure how correct this is:

Tn = (n * (n + 1) * (n + 2)) / 6

The proof uses the fact that the nth tetrahedral
the number is given by,

Trin = (n * (n + 1)) / 2

It proceeds by induction.

Base Case

T1 = 1 = 1 * 2 * 3 / 6

Inductive Step

Tn+1 = Tn + Trin+1

Tn+1 = [((n * (n + 1) * (n + 2)) / 6] + [((n + 1) * (n + 2)) / 2]

Tn+1 = (n * (n + 1) * (n + 2)) / 6

Comment: Your final line does not make sense.  Try extracting the factor $\frac{(n + 1)(n + 2)}{2}$ from both terms in the previous line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing some of your braces and asterisks, your last but one equation is
$$
T_{n+1} = n (n + 1) (n + 2) / 6 + (n + 1) (n + 2) / 2
$$
This is correct, now notice that rearranging the above gives you
$$
\begin{align}
T_{n+1} 
&= (n + 1) (n + 2)(n/6+1/2)\\
&=(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)/6\\
&=n'(n'+1)(n'+2)/6\\
\end{align}
$$
where $n'=n+1$.

This is all you needed to do.

By the way, please be careful when stacking oranges.

[image]

Comment: How would I go about solving a similar question: Let Sn be the number of oranges visible on the three upward-facing sides of the tetrahedron. Derive a closed-form formula for Sn and determine how many levels the stack would have to have before more than half of the oranges are hidden. Note from the diagram that Sn= Cnfor n = 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 3):

this is called Pascal's Triangle...the triangular numbers are in a diagonal, the tetrahedral numbers (which are also the 12 days of Christmas  cumulative gifts)  are the next diagonal.
[image]